# How to capture TCP packets sent from client to TCP server(STM32H767)

Tags: c, networking, tcp, stm32, lwip

I am trying to make my STM32F767 board capture TCP values sent from my computer. I am using the STM32 board as the TCP server. When i send TCP packets to my board, my board returns back an acknowledgment but I am having a hard time trying to capture that data and hold it.

Here is my code.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
extern struct netif gnetif;
struct tcp_pcb* tcp_echoserver_pcb;
struct tcp_pcb* newpcb;
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  ip_addr_t myIPADDR,destip;
  IP_ADDR4(&myIPADDR,192,168,33,1);
  IP_ADDR4(&destip,192,168,33,101);

  tcp_echoserver_pcb = tcp_new();

  err_t err = tcp_bind(tcp_echoserver_pcb, &myIPADDR, 8);

  if(err == ERR_OK)
    {
      tcp_echoserver_pcb = tcp_listen(tcp_echoserver_pcb);
      tcp_accept(tcp_echoserver_pcb, tcp_echoserver_accept);

    }

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      ethernetif_input(&gnetif);
      sys_check_timeouts();

      tcp_arg(tcp_echoserver_pcb, newpcb);
      tcp_recv(tcp_echoserver_pcb, recv_callback);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}


err_t tcp_echoserver_accept(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *newpcb, err_t err)
{

}
err_t recv_callback(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *tpcb, struct pbuf *p, err_t err)
{

    tcp_write(tpcb, p->payload, p->len, TCP_WRITE_FLAG_COPY);
    tcp_output(tpcb);

    tcp_recved(tpcb, p->len);
    return ERR_OK;
}
```

Comment: Presumably you have the data available in `recv_callback()`. What's the problem?

Comment: @pmacfarlane, Thanks for the reply. I setup a blinking led in infinite loop to check if the control ever enters the recv_callback(), but as it turns out, the control never enters the recv_callback() for some reason.